# Generate a connected line with different amplitude

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game like [Line](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nmssoftware.line.android&hl=en&gl=US), but with a horizontal and not vertical wave. The problem is making that the wave continues even after changing its amplitude (I will change the frequency later). So far I have reached this part of wave:

```py
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math
import time

DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H = 400, 800

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
GAME_DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))


class Line():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pointsList = [0]*800
        self.listIndex = 0

    def game(self):
        while True:
            clock.tick(60)
            SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.listIndex += +1
            self.generateWave()
            self.drawWave()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    quit()
            pygame.display.update()
            GAME_DISPLAY.blit(SCREEN, (0, 0))

    def drawWave(self):
        for Y_CORD in range(len(self.pointsList)):
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(
                    GAME_DISPLAY, self.pointsList[Y_CORD]-55, DISPLAY_H-Y_CORD, (255, 255, 255))
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(
                    GAME_DISPLAY, self.pointsList[Y_CORD]-350, DISPLAY_H-Y_CORD, (255, 255, 255))
    def generateWave(self):
        waveAmplitude = 50
        waveFrequency = 1
        XCord = int((DISPLAY_H/2) + waveAmplitude*math.sin(
            waveFrequency * ((float(0)/-DISPLAY_W)*(2*math.pi) + (time.time()))))

        if self.pointsList[-1] != 0:
            self.pointsList.pop(0)
            self.pointsList.append(XCord)
        else:
            self.pointsList[self.listIndex] = XCord


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Line()
    game.game()
```

I thought about having another function to change the amplitude, but then there would be a gap:
[image: lineGap]

Comment: You know the ending coordinate of the last segment, right?  Can't you always use that as the starting coordinate for the new segment?

Comment: yes i know, but then what can i change in the wave so it would have a curve in it?, it is either the amplitude or the frequency to change

Comment: Yes, it's a bit tricky.  One key is, don't regenerate the whole wave each time.  Just add one new point at a time.  If the new X is far from the old X, you'll want to move it a bit at a time, to "sneak up" on the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)

Splines have many nice properties, on purpose,
such as matching the slope of inbound and outbound
curve segments.  But you're not using splines
in the current code, so let's switch gears.

---

For current `y`
you can phrase this in terms of `hidden_x`
and `display_x` coordinates.

The trouble with the hidden X is, as you mentioned,
it sadly is discontinuous.
Which would make for an ugly display.
So we won't do that.

But it's a perfectly good *ideal* to shoot for.
So let's run with that notion.
Initialize `display_x` to equal `hidden_x`.

Now as Y advances, the hidden value can jump
around disconcertingly, even discontinuously.
Define some parameter `alpha` on the unit interval 0 .. 1.
Compute

```
    delta = hidden_x - display_x
```

For each new Y, advance `display_x`
*in the right direction*
by `alpha * delta`.
Thus, no matter how the hidden X jumps around,
the display X will always *smoothly* be chasing it.

```
    display_x += alpha * delta
```

Imagine that alpha was set to 1.0.
Then we're essentially assigning the hidden value
to the display value, right?

For positive values *less* than 1,
the display value will head in the right direction,
and soon will almost catch up to where
the hidden variable is.
Choosing an appropriate `alpha` value is up to you.
Largely it's an aesthetic decision,
given that OP did not disclose how errors affect
a cost function.
Play with it, have fun!

---

For more details on this technique,
look into [PID controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).
Feel free to ignore the integration term.
What we've been looking at are
the Position and Derivative terms.
The PID literature might give you
ideas on how to formalize "goodness of fit"
in your use case.

---

Non-linear transforms might be applicable,
as well.

```
    assert delta >= 0
    display_x += max(max_delta, alpha * delta)
```

Sometimes we describe this as clipping
the derivative to a maximum [slew rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate).
(If you choose to adopt this approach,
be sure to use something like [sgn()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)
so that both positive and negative deltas
are handled appropriately.)

Some folks might even prefer to use a quadratic
relation with `delta`,
in order to catch up to "big" swings more quickly.

Comment: I don't get your point in making hidden_x and display_x, and later you say "Initialize display_x to equal hidden_x.", and what is PID have to do with all this, can you include more references?

I studied about the Spline but i'm not trying to make a curve here with different control points, they aren't defined by a fixed amount of points.

Comment: You showed us a discontinuous function and wanted it to be smoothly differentiable, to look nice. I suggested techniques, such as from the PD controller literature, which allow quickly converging on that driving function and then smoothly tracking it through any subsequent discontinuities. Consider a mob of six-year olds chasing a soccer ball. The ball's location is the hidden_x driving function, and the players are attracted to it, they slowly follow it. Similar setup to the proposed solution. You could instead wrap a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) around it.